# How to autoscroll when mouse is near the edge of window

Tags: cocoa, autoscroll

I have an (big) NSImageView embedded in an (smaller) NSScrollView. I want to automatically scroll if the mouse goes near the edge of the window, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an NSTrackingArea to be notified when the mouse enters a particular area of a view and then use one of NSResponder's scroll.. routines to scroll the view.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa has a built in method called [NSView.autoscroll(with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483471-autoscroll) which will automatically scroll the enclosing scroll view when tracking mouse events and the cursor is outside of the scroll view's clip view.